# JSF inputHidden ,How can I disable them dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I have these JSF inputHidden, I need that at the time of confirmation button , they are disabled via JS or JQuery. Can someone tell me how to do it?

I use them only to take values from the backend, after which I do not need them anymore.

```
<h:inputHidden id="Xlist" rendered="true" value="#{praticheDettaglioController.listaXUbicazionePratichePendenti}" />
<h:inputHidden id="Ylist" rendered="true" value="#{praticheDettaglioController.listaYUbicazionePratichePendenti}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `h:outputText` with `display:none` style which would be rendered as a `<span>` element and would not be posted back at all:

```
<h:outputText id="Xlist"
  value="#{praticheDettaglioController.listaXUbicazionePratichePendenti}"
  style="display:none;"/>
<h:outputText id="Ylist"
  value="#{praticheDettaglioController.listaYUbicazionePratichePendenti}"
  style="display:none;"/>
```

A furhter alternative is to have your values assigned to simple javascript variables:

```
<h:outputScript>
  var Xlist = '#{praticheDettaglioController.listaXUbicazionePratichePendenti}';
  var Ylist = '#{praticheDettaglioController.listaYUbicazionePratichePendenti}';
</h:outputScript>
```

This way, you can read them anywhere in javascript.

Comment: InputHidden are always invisible, but their functionality is not. I tried and it does not change anything.

Comment: What would you expect to change? @ChristianScarselli

Answer (score 3):

Use `inputText` with `type="hidden"` and `disabled="true"` instead like :

```
<p:inputText id="Xlist" value="..." type="hidden" disabled="true"/>
<p:inputText id="Ylist" value="..." type="hidden" disabled="true"/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not a commit phase, this happens when the page confirmation key is pressed. These values go to a controller where they are not needed and give an error.

Comment: `h:inputHidden` does not have `disabled` property. You'll need a pass through in this case.

Comment: @ChristianScarselli edit your question and add the error details please (e.g. stack trace at least). Your current question as a XY one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Selaron The mistake is that the confirmation button is connected to a java controller that has no functionality to receive that data, and it does not have to. For this it is necessary to disable them when the button is pressed. Just find in javascript or Jquery a way to set the "rendered" parameter of the inputHidden to false.

Comment: @ChristianScarselli the rendered attribute cannot be set from a javascript. It's a server side attribute evaluated during render response phase and not present in client side DOM at all.

Comment: @ChristianScarselli what about using `<p:inputText id="Xlist" value="..." type="hidden" disabled="true"/>`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I thought I had to use inputHidden, I did not think you could hide p: text too. It works, thank you very much, you saved me! Thanks also to everyone else.

Comment: Glad I could help @ChristianScarselli , if the answer is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** for the future readers.